# How to check whether in WiFi scan throttling is enable or disable?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-9.0-pie, android-10.0

I have a development scenario where I need to check whether WiFi throttling option is enable or disable?
If it is enable than I want to disable it programmatically.

```
private fun prepareForWiFiScan() {

 Toast.makeText(this, "Wifi scan preparation started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        circularProgressbar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        wiFiManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager
        if (!wiFiManager.isWifiEnabled) {
            wiFiManager.isWifiEnabled = true
        }
        wiFiScanReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Wifi scan finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).senter code herehow()
                val i'sSuccess: Boolean = when {
                    android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M -> intent.getBooleanExtra(
                            WifiManager.EXTRA_RESULTS_UPDATED,
                            false
                    )
                    else -> intent.getBooleanExtra(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION, false)
                }
                circularProgressbar.visibility = View.GONE
                when (isSuccess) {
                    true -> scanSuccess()
                    false -> scanFail()
                }
            }
        }
        registerReceiverAndStartScan()
    }

 private fun registerReceiverAndStartScan() {
        val intentFilter = IntentFilter()
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION)
        registerReceiver(wiFiScanReceiver, intentFilter)
        val success = wiFiManager.startScan()
        if (!success) {
            scanFail()
        }
    }
```

Comment: It would be good if you provided us with a code snippet of your work.

Answer (score 1):

There are no way present until android 10 where we can check whether WiFi scan throttle is enable or disable. However in android R the new method added to check whether WiFi Scan throttling is enable or disable.
Please refer following link.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#isScanThrottleEnabled()

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can also check the wifi throttle in Android versions < 10 by using

```
Settings.Global.getInt(this.getContentResolver(), "wifi_scan_throttle_enabled")
```

It returns `1` if wifi throttle is enabled, `0` otherwise

Comment: The key does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a broadcastReceiver for receiving this. Check here
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-scan

Answer (score 0):

This works via a root command shell in android 11. Returns false if "Wi-Fi scan throttling" is disabled in developer options. Wish there was an easier way to set this value via a command vs having to set it via multiple presses of the android GUI.

```
dumpsys wifi | grep wifi_scan_throttle_enabled
```